# Creating a list of lists from an input file

Tags: python, list

I have an input file with multiple values per line, e.g:

```
1  3  5

2  6  1

8  9  2
```

I want to import these numbers to a list of lists, so that each line is a list within a list of lists:

`data= [[1 3 5], [2 6 1], [8 9 2]]` etc.

Is there an easy way of doing this? I've looked at `readline`, `readlines`, `lines`, but am still not sure how to create this format. Ultimately, I'd like to perform the same set of operations on each of the lists, so this format seems the most sensible.

Comment: `data = [map(int, l.split(' ')) for l in fh.readlines()]`?

Comment: @g.d.d.c, Cool and concise, but shouldn't you add an `if l` at the end of the generator? According to the OP's question, there are empty lines in the file.

Comment: @BorrajaX That would work, or you could `filter(bool, fh.readlines())`. (That is a list comprehension, not a generator.)

Comment: Wooo! That's right! Even cooler!!, @Two-Bit Alchemist!! **:-D**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
data = [map(int, line.split()) for line in fname if line.strip()]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you data looks just the way you presented it, try something like:

```
data = []
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip(): continue #skips blank lines
        data.append(map(int, line.strip().split(" "))) #or .split()
```

Additionally, if you will be doing the same numerical operations on each of the rows, you may want to try `numpy`.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: np.genfromtxt('filename.txt')
Out[2]: 
array([[ 1.,  3.,  5.],
       [ 2.,  6.,  1.],
       [ 8.,  9.,  2.]])

In [3]: x = np.genfromtxt('filename.txt')
In [4]: x.mean(axis=1)
Out[4]: array([ 3.,  3.,  6.333333333333333])
```

Comment: Why `split(" ")`? It will already split on whitespace, and if it's more than one space between digits this solution will not work. (With no arguments, it's good for any amount of whitespace.)

Comment: Fair enough, though I find it better to be explicit.  This may also alert OP to formatting problems in the file.